# Autocompletion, history and scrolling in Byobu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, byobu

I am using an Ubuntu server with Byobu. For some reason, the tab key writes a tab instead of completing commands and paths. Top arrow writes `^[[A` instead of the command history. Scrolling writes `^[[B`. I'm wondering how to solve this: is this a byobu configuration problem, a keyboard problem?

Comment: Do you have package `libreadline` installed?

Comment: `libreadline6` is installed.

Comment: What's your terminal?  gnome-terminal?  putty?  xterm?  This sounds like a terminal issue.

Comment: I use Terminal.app but other shells work fine.

Answer (score 0):

To make byobu aware of your terminal's capabilities you might want to try setting `TERM=xterm` or something compatible like that. Also in Terminal.app's settings, under *Advanced Settings* you can choose from several types of 'xterm' under the *Emulation Options* section. If this doesn't work then we might have to fiddle about with the byobu configuration to let it know explicitly that you have a modern terminal capable of using these kinds of characters.

I'm not a Mac user, but as a side note, you might also want to consider using [iTerm2](http://www.iterm2.com/#/section/home) which apparently has more features.